# I need to analyze all rows in a dataframe and check if a value exists in any column

Tags: python, dataframe

I am currently trying to check if a value exists in each row of a dataframe and if it is the case, a variable value should change. I am thinking about something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'1': ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2'], '2': ['molear', 'laurylh'], '3': ["131", "132"], '4': ["3", "4"], '5': ["133", "131"], '6': ["3", "4"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

C="0"

for i1 in df1.loc[0]:
    if (i1=="131"):
        C="Result1"
```

But this only works for the first row. Is there a way to do this for every row in a dataframe? The idea is to make a second dataframe which will store the C value in every row related to the df1. Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you provide a sample of your expected output based on the provided input? The "second dataframe which will store the C value..." piece?

Comment: I would suggest changing the Question's Title using the correct words.  Try:  How to find rows that match in a dataframe?   But once you've properly identified this question, then won't need to ask this question at Stack because you can easily find the solution yourself from the web or from similar questions that were already asked.

Comment: Re-reading your question: are you asking to set a value in a column `'C'` of a dataframe to some value based on a value existing anywhere on the row, for every row?

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you are looking for is `df.iterrows()`. It loops over each row of the dataframe. However it is not recommended because on big data this might take much time.
Let's say that you are looking in '1' column then the code might look like.

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['1']='131':
        C="Result1"
```

You can check this page too https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know df.iterrows() but the problem is that I need to check all colums per row and try to find if there is a '131'. I was thinking about something like this:

```
C='131 is not present'

X=0

   

for index, row in df1.iterrows():

    for i1 in df1.loc[X]:

        if (i1=="131"):

            C='131 is present in this row' 

            X=X+1       

        print(i1)
```

The problem now is that I do not know how could I fill a new dataframe (df2, which is currently empty) with the C result in each row. For example, if df1 has 50 rows, I would like to fill 50 rows in df2 with the C result saying if 131 is present or not in this row (according to what I have in df1). Thanks!